# Can I still send back the tracking data of IER to Salesforce even after doing a send?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, marketing-cloud-connect, email-studio

We have a Salesforce CRM and IER is enabled. I sent out an email using guided-send/user-initiated and the DE coming from the Data Extension folder only, is there a way to send the IER tracking data even after doing the send?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The workaround is to create these missing IER records through Automation Studio script activity or Journey Builder salesforce object activity. You can use Data Views to find the proper content.

Comment: I am already done getting the data in the data views, and now, im having trouble using the Journey Builder Salesforce Object Activity to map the fields into the IER Object because it is not inserting.